# iOS 8: How to use segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, segue

I am really confused about segues. There are so many different ways to change the current ViewController and I don't know which to use and mix them up.

What I currently have, is a MainViewController. On this I have 4 Buttons. The first button is connected with a Show (e.g Push) Segue. On the other side of the Segue is a Navigation Controller with a View Controller. Now this works with no additional code.

Now my first Question. The Navigation Controller will never be shown, right? Only the View Controller will be shown. But if I want to add a Navigation Item Button on the right side to go back to the first View Controller how should I do it? I need to add the button programmatic like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftBackToPreviousScreenButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                              initWithTitle:@""
                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                              target:self
                                              action:@selector(back)];

- (void)back
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ExitEventOverview" sender:self];
}
```

Is this right?

Now the next step is, that I need to open another View to edit details of an event which are shown in the previous View as a table. When I click on the table row the Edit View should open and I need to pass the event object. How do I do this with segues?
After finishing editing how can I add programmatic a Cancel and Save button to the Edit View do return to the Overview of all Events?

Comment: These questions are very broad, I'd suggest trying to narrow your problem down to a single, more specific question. Have you read [the "Using Segues" section of the View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH15-SW1)?

Comment: Why doesn't the navigation controller hold everything?

Comment: Well the problem is that there are many tutorials etc. but each shows something else. Now I don't know which is the best way to do the thing I described. I mean I currently have a project in which the segues work. But the code still feels wrong :)

Comment: in initially it happen , every tutorial does not give proper answer, some tutorials may be given correctly else part we need to customize what ever we need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your coding is fine and add following line also

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftBackToPreviousScreenButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                          initWithTitle:@""
                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                          target:self
                                          action:@selector(back)];

// add this line 
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = leftBackToPreviousScreenButton;

- (void)back
{
// if you want to pop on previous view controller

 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

in last question you need to  customize ,but if you need to pass the data between two view controller use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to implement a `UINavigationController` and put assign your `UIViewController` with 4 buttons as `root view controller`. Show segues presents the navigation bar but the others don't, in that case you need to manage it and to add it.

To show the details, just override the method `prepareForSegue:sender` to do so :

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NextSegue" sender:nil];

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"NextSegue"]) {
        NextViewController *nextViewController = (NextViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        nextViewController.details = self.details;
        // nextViewController.details is the property "details" declared in your NextViewController.h file, you just give it the value you want to send from your present one.
    }
}
```